# Oracle の insert all 後、なぜ DUAL テーブルを select しないといけない？

Tags: oracle

Oracleにて複数レコードinsertしたい時、なぜ最後にDUALテーブルをSELECTしないといけないのでしょうか？

```
insert all 
insert into table() values()
   .....
insert into table() values()
select * from dual
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSERT ALL`の構文がサブクエリを必要とするため、必ずSELECT文が必要であることが主な理由です。
特にサブクエリの値を使わない場合の慣例としてDUAL表を使用します。

公式ドキュメントの[Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2111652)から`multi_table_insert ::=`を確認すると、`INSERT ALL`の構文は必ず末尾にサブクエリ(subquery)を必要としていて省略できません。
[subquery](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#sthref9453)の説明を見ても省略できない理由は書かれていないので、[Example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2126076)からOracleが元々想定しているサブクエリの使い方を推測してみます。

ExampleのSQLを抜粋して加工したものが下記です。

```
INSERT ALL
      INTO sales (prod_id, cust_id, time_id, amount)
      VALUES (product_id, customer_id, weekly_start_date, sales_sun)
      INTO sales (prod_id, cust_id, time_id, amount)
      VALUES (product_id, customer_id, weekly_start_date+1, sales_mon)
      INTO sales (prod_id, cust_id, time_id, amount)
      VALUES (product_id, customer_id, weekly_start_date+2, sales_tue)
      -- 以下略
   SELECT product_id, customer_id, weekly_start_date, sales_sun,
      sales_mon, sales_tue, sales_wed, sales_thu, sales_fri, sales_sat
      FROM sales_input_table;
```

上記のINSERT文の例では、`sales_input_table`に3レコード入っています。
`weekly_start_date`に0日、1日、2日を加算して`sales`テーブルに入れているので、日付のみインクリメントしながら計9レコードを`sales`テーブルに追加します。

```
INSERT ALL
   WHEN order_total < 1000000 THEN
      INTO small_orders
   WHEN order_total > 1000000 AND order_total < 2000000 THEN
      INTO medium_orders
   WHEN order_total > 2000000 THEN
      INTO large_orders
   SELECT order_id, order_total, sales_rep_id, customer_id
      FROM orders;
```

上記の例では、`order_total`カラムの値によってINSERTする先のテーブルを`small_orders`,`medium_orders`,`large_orders`に振り分けています。

Oracleとしてはテーブルの値を元にして、レコードごとに値の変わらないカラムのコピーや日付/連番の加算、CASE文による挿入先の条件分岐を意図しているようです。
個人の想像ですが、`values`に定数のみを指定する使い方は重視しておらず「値が決め打ちなら普通に`INSERT INTO`を並べればいいじゃん」と考えたのかもしれません。

結論としては「構文上SELECT文を付けなければいけないので、仕方なく1行だけ値が返る最軽量のSQL文を書かなければいけない」となります。